# Timber Wordpress (TWIG) - Dynamic Sidebar

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, timber

I am net to Timber and TWIG.
I can't get the **dynamic sidebar** to show up. My goal is for the content to only show up if there is a **dynamic sidebar** and you are on the **front-page.php**. Currently it tells me that there is widget area, however I am not on the correct page. I am sure that **front-page.php** is getting rendered however.
I am working with the [**Timber starter theme (Github)**](https://github.com/timber/starter-theme) for Wordpress as a base.
I can get the Widgets to show, if I add the code directly which I commented out in the **front-page.twig**

**sidebar.php**

```
#Timber::render( array( 'sidebar.twig' ), $data ); if i understand right, i can remove this?

$context = array();
$context['dynamic_sidebar'] = Timber::get_widgets('home_sidebar');
Timber::render('sidebar.twig', $context);
```

**functions.php** i added this to the end of the file:

```
function custom_widgets_init() {

    register_sidebar( array(
        'id'          => 'home_sidebar',
        'name'        => __( 'Dynamic Sidebar 1', $text_domain ),
        'description' => __( 'This sidebar is located on the left side of the content.', $text_domain ),
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'custom_widgets_init' );
```

**font-page.twig**

```
{% extends "base.twig" %}

{# STUFF #}

{% block sidebar_area %}

        <aside>
            {{dynamic_sidebar}}
            {# {% do function('dynamic_sidebar', 'dynamic-sidebar-1') %} THIS HOWEVER WORKS #}
        </aside>

{% endblock %}
```

**sidebar.twig** : is currently empty

Comment: I have the feeling that I should actually add the content from my sidebar.php to front-page.php which currently doesn't exist. Will test this once I am back home.

Comment: That didn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

@frizzant: if you haven't already check out the guide we put together for sidebars:

https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/sidebars/